# Referencing SQL model in mongoengine model field

Tags: django, mongoengine

I'm using [mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/) in my workout calendar Django project to store workouts with varying fields, depending on which lifts a user has done, how many of them, etc.

I have defined a `Workout` object that represents one workout done by one person at a certain date.

```
class Workout(Document):
    id = IntField(unique=True, null=False)
    date = DateTimeField()
    lifts = EmbeddedDocumentListField(LiftSerie)
    cardio = EmbeddedDocumentListField(CardioSerie)
```

Some of you might notice that there is no field representing the person who did the workout. That is where my question comes in. In my Django project, I have defined a custom `User` model that I've used instead of the normal `django.contrib.auth.models.User` object:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        },
    )
```

This model is a normal Django model, and is represented in an SQL database, SQLite in my case. I would like this model to act as the `user` field in my `Workout` mongoengine model. Something like this:

```
class Workout(Document):
    id = IntField(unique=True, null=False)
    date = DateTimeField()
    lifts = EmbeddedDocumentListField(LiftSerie)
    cardio = EmbeddedDocumentListField(CardioSerie)
    person = ReferenceField(User) #New row
```

Is this possible to achieve in some way? Or do I need to introduce redundancy to my web app by simply adding an `email` field to my mongoengine model to represent a user (email is a unique field in `User`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement a custom model manager that implements the query you're asking for by using [`db_manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases)

You're implementing a good amount of extra complexity by using two different database types.  If I were you, I'd look at simplify your database infrastructure by leveraging the NoSQL and JSON capabilities of Postgres.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Is this what you're talking about? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/

Comment: correct, specifically [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield)